# Smooth render using Three.js objloader

Tags: three.js

Anyone can explain me how to have smooth render with objloader using three.js ?

I try to found , but nothing matches.

Thank's

Comment: `material.shading = THREE.SmoothShading` is the default. Can you show a link to your live example?

Comment: Yep, 

http://ivanvujnovic.com/Avatar_final/index.html

Thanks